# ASP.NET: how to commit postback only after client ajax is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a button encoded as such:

```
<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"
                ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="a= saveAllFilt();  return a; "
                OnClick="save_all_filt_Click" />
```

saveAllFilt is a function that invokes usual JQuery ajax call. Something like this:

```
  function saveAllFilt() {
   jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    url: contentURL,
    data: dataarray,
    success: function (msg) {
        // Some processing here. ONLY WHEN IT IS DONE, I NEED TO HAVE POSTBACK.
    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});         // end of ajax call.
```

}

I want such a thing: the onClick should proceed only after ajax call is complete. How I can do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the `OnClick` attribute from the button and return false in the `OnClientClick` attribute like:

```
<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"
            ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="saveAllFilt(); return false;" />
```

and set a hidden button with that `OnClick` attribute like:

```
<asp:Button ID="hdnButton" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="save_all_filt_Click" />
```

and in the success method of your `ajax` call click that button like:

```
success: function (msg) {
    // Some processing here. ONLY WHEN IT IS DONE, I NEED TO HAVE POSTBACK.
    $('#hdnButton').click();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

it is quite easy. Call your postback method in success function. 
Chekout the following code.

change your markup

```
<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"
ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="a=saveAllFilt();  return false;"
OnClick="save_all_filt_Click" />
```

change your java script code

```
function saveAllFilt() {
   jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    url: contentURL,
    data: dataarray,
    success: function (msg) {
        // Some processing here.Now do the post postback
        <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(save_all_filt,"") %>

    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Your idea seems pretty strange to me.Why you are trying to call ajax  before postback.

Answer (score 0):

You're not far from getting it right.

Instead of:

`<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"                  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="a= saveAllFilt();  return a; "                  OnClick="save_all_filt_Click" />`

Try:

`<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"                 ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return saveAllFilt()"                 OnClick="save_all_filt_Click" />`

The difference is that instead of `OnClientClick="a= saveAllFilt();  return a;"` just do `OnClientClick="return saveAllFilt()"`

Answer (score 0):

If return true is not working inside the ajax success function. use __postback fucntion inside the ajax success function.

this will commit postback only after the ajax call complete.

Comment: Please could you explain how this resolves his problem ?

Comment: Just search on Google syntax of__postback function in javascript. Just call this__postback function in success block of jQuery ajax function.

Answer (score -1):

In the function call,

```
 OnClientClick="return saveAllFilt()";
```

In Ajax,

return true for if the ajax call is success and return false for every other cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `return true` after your code in your `.ajax()` calls's `success` attribute. The priority is always this way :

- The client -side
- Server side

Only if the client returns `true` the server click will initiate.

```
function saveAllFilt() {
  jQuery.ajax({
     async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    url: contentURL,
    data: dataarray,
    success: function (msg) {
       // Some processing here. ONLY WHEN IT IS DONE, I NEED TO HAVE POSTBACK.
       return true;
   },
   error: function (data) {
       return false;
   }
 });
}
```

Also, remove the `onclick` attribute - an non-performant attribute in HTML (in my opinion) and use jquery's `on()`.