# ASP.NET PostBack after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working with a legacy web application - there's a form with some text inputs and some file inputs, and the form is saved on a PostBack..

HTML:

```
<input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text" />
<input id="hfd1" name="hfd1" type="hidden" value="-1" />
<input id="file1" name="file1" runat="server" type="file" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="return PrepareSave()" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
```

JS:

```
function PrepareSave() {
    $('#hfd1').val($('#txt1').val());
    return true;
}
```

I need to send an AJAX request inside `PrepareSave()` to validate a field on the server, and depending on the response, carry on with the PostBack or don't. I've tried this:

```
function PrepareSave() {
    Project1.Web.Services.AJAXService1.CheckSomething(someString, function (result) {
        if (result == true) {
            // continue PostBack
            $('#hfd1').val($('#txt1').val());
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // abort PostBack
            alert('invalid');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

But it's failing - it doesn't post back regardless of the AJAX response. I've tried implementing the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916884/asp-net-how-to-commit-postback-only-after-client-ajax-is-complete) but it's having the same problems. What can I do to make it work?

I've tried simplifying that accepted answer above, to test it:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="PrepareSave(); return false;" Text="Save" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveHidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Visible="False" />

function PrepareSave() {
    $('#btnSaveHidden').click(); // does nothing. also tried .trigger('click')
}
```

Comment: problem is that ajax is async. Your form doesn't know to wait for the result. And `return` in your ajax callback does not not return a value from the PrepareSave(). If you don't return explicitly a value from a JS function, then any calling code that tries to read the return value gets a false-y value by default. Hence why the postback is stopped. Basically you need to cancel the postback, make your ajax call, and then if it's ok, then trigger the submit again programatically. or you could do all your validation inside the postback to simplify things, if that's practical.

Comment: I agree, for your needs (as I get it here) a server validation should do the job. If you want to do sth async and you rely on webforms I suggest using an Updatepanel

Comment: Thanks for both of your inputs here. @DotNetDev, yeah except this form is a modal screen, so doing the validation without ajax will be a bit painful.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind you can do:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ReloadParent", "window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;", true);
```

or in js, use the script part by itself:

```
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;
```

hth.